# Why is it 'Next of Kin' instead of just 'Kin'?

Tags: meaning, phrase-origin, confusables

Newspaper reports are abound with the phrase *Next of Kin* especially in the context of accidents.

Kin is defined as One's family and relations.
Next of Kin is defined as A person's closest living relative(s).

I don't get the difference between the two. Wouldn't just Kin suffice for all purposes. Or rather, wouldn't *Next* of kin mean *relatives of relatives*? What is the origin and context of *Next* in *Next of Kin*?

Comment: Next of kin is the *closest* living relative, possibly more than one equally closely related. It’s a legal concept.  A brother is closer than a nephew or cousin.

Comment: You seem to have included the answer within your question. *Relations* is a much bigger group than *closest living relatives*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*next of kin*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/next%20of%20kin) (emphasis mine):

> : one or more persons in **the nearest degree of relationship** to another person

Taking that meaning and inserting omitted words (in the particular context of a death), it can be paraphrased as follows:

- Next <sup>[in line of inheritance and responsibility]</sup> of <sup>[the remaining]</sup> kin.

It's not talking about *all* of the person's family and relations (which would simply be *kin*), but only those who are the closest to the deceased. Legally, it would only be those who have some kind of responsibility or duty to take care of with respect to the person.

For instance, a spouse, sibling, parent, or child would likely be included in the next of kin. A cousin, especially one who had not spoken to the person in  many years, likely would not be.